# Variable not set inside listener?

Tags: android, firebase, authentication, kotlin

I'm trying to set my variable inside the sign in function provided by firebase.

I tried moving my variable to become a global variable, but that didn't seem to do it.
**isValid** is my problem variable. It seems to authenticate successfully and logs the case is true, however, the value doesn't stay true outside of that.

```
auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this) {task ->
                // why doesn't this set isvalid to true
                this.isValid = if(task.isSuccessful) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "hey auth actually worked!")
                    true
                } else {
                    Log.d(TAG, "let's try that again")
                    false
                }
            }
```

I'm initializing isValid to be false and even though I'm setting it to be true as seen above, the value is still false.

Comment: `signInWithEmailAndPassword` is asynchronous and returns immediately before the callback is called.  Are you sure you aren't just trying to check `isValid` before the callback happens?

Comment: Lol, I just realized that, I added more logs and I realized the variable gets set after I'm done with the method. And can you explain what you mean? Because I am trying to figure out if the user has a valid email/password, so I need that variable to be set before I return the method

Comment: That won't be possible without blocking the method, which probably also means blocking the main thread, which also means possibly causing an ANR.  Don't do that.  Firebase APIs are all asynchronous by design, and you should be dealing with them as such.  Just don't try to block a method on async work.    https://medium.com/google-developers/why-are-firebase-apis-asynchronous-callbacks-promises-tasks-e037a6654a93

Comment: The easiest thing is to just call another function from within your callback, to continue where you left off.

Comment: That seems WAY easier, however I don't understand, because the callback is happening after my method is finished right? So even though I'm calling a function to set my value, doesn't that happen after everything's done?

Comment: That worked, but I don't understand how it worked. Please explain it to me, if you have time + interest

Comment: I would suggest doing some web searches to look for resources about asynchronous programming.

Comment: Gotcha thanks for the help. Wish I could mark your answer as correct!